# How do I convert AVMetadataItem value to NSDate or NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nslog, avmetadataitem

I am trying to get the date a video was taken and populate a TextView with it in Xcode.  I have chosen the video and then gotten the date from the AVMetadataItem creationDate.  I can print it out as a NSLog but I want to convert it into a String or NSData.
Here is my code in objective-c

in .h

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nullable) AVMetadataItem *creationDate;
```

and in .m

```
NSURL * movieURL = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ;
       AVURLAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:movieURL options:nil];
        NSLog(@"creationDate:%@",anAsset.creationDate.value);
```

in the log I get creationDate:Tue Jan 26 09:44:39 2021 which is the date I took the video.
My problem is now converting it to a usable form.

When I try

```
NSString = anAsset.creationDate.value;
```

I get a warning

```
Initializing 'NSString *_strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<NSObject,NSCopying> _Nullable'
```

I basically get this same warning no matter what I try.

Can someone help me get this working?

Comment: `NSDate *creationDate = (NSDate *)anAsset.creationDate.value` ? Or `NSString *creationDate = (NSString *)anAsset.creationDate.value` it depends if that's supposed to be a `NSDate` or a `NSString` object.

Comment: Do you know if there is a GPS  metadata value stored with video?